# Have the tallest div dictate the height of a row

Tags: css, position, css-float

I have to create a row of 3 divs with varying heights, but they all must be aligned to the bottom of the row and the row must be the height of the tallest child div.

Here's an example of what I mean.

http://cl.ly/997cd739550635df3bbf

Here's what I attempted:

```
div1 {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
}

.div2 {
height: 100%;
float: left;
width: 300px
position: relative;
}

.row {
}
```

But unless I set the height of .row all of the div2s stack on top of each other. Is there any way to be able to have the row's height be fluid depending on the tallest child div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your are using `position:absolute` (and `position:relative`) when you only need to float the divs.

`position:absolute` apart from fixing the position of the div in the page takes it out of the normal flow of the page (that is, is put in another layer), that is the reason why your divs are stacking.

I suggest mark the divs with `display:inline-block` and use `vertical-align:bottom` instead of `bottom`.

Comment: Thank you that was the solution :) I just needed to use inline-block + vertical-align: bottom instead of floating left.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the float is not needed with `inline-block`, in fact is better don't use it to avoid when not needed. Just the habit on having to use it when `inline-block` didn't worked in all browsers...

Answer (score 0):

What about in CSS:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: bottom;
```